# SAS how to get summary counts within the same dataset

Tags: count, sas, summary

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
id,colour
12,blue
12,green
12,yellow
13,blue
14,black
15,blue
15,green
```

In the same data set I would like to have the counts of each id
Ultimately what I want to do is eliminate the ids that have more than one

In SQL I would use a SUM OVER() windowing function, or self join the table with the counts of each id

Whats the best way to do this in SAS?

```
id,colour,num
12,blue,3
12,green,3
12,yellow,3
13,blue,1
14,black,1
15,blue,2
15,green,2
```

My end result is going to look like this in the end after excluding the duplicate ids:

```
id,colour
13,blue
14,black
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use PROC SORT in SAS 9.3+ to get a set of unique observations by key variables.

```
proc sort data=have out=duprec nouniquekey uniqueout=want;
by id;
run;
```

In SAS SQL you could remerge directly - something that isn't supported in other versions of SQL. You could further limit the query with a HAVING clause to get your final output directly.

```
proc sql;
create table want3 as
select *
from have
group by id
having count(*)=1;
quit;
```

Comment: NOUNIQUEKEY is one of my favorite 9.3+ additions.  Super handy.

Comment: sounds great but unfortunately i dont have 9.3 i have 9.2

Comment: great i see what the SQL suggestion is doing now - which like you say is not supported in other versions of SQL